# find the change cause of last access time.

Tags: unix

I'm trying to find out who is the user that change the
"Access" time of a file or directory. (that appear in `stat` command on Unix).

I mean, to get more information about the last access time (atime).

is that a way to find it?

thank you.

Comment: If it's linux (2.6 kernerl or higher) and "audit" is installed and configured to watch the file in question, then there's a good chance you may be able to find out.

Comment: IF you would tell us the UNIX platform we could give you a decent answer.  For example inotify in Linux can do that.  Other UNIX systems have completely different tools.

Comment: I'm using:  Linux version 3.0.51-0.7.9-default